# player-3.0.2 and player 3.1.0 - 'interface_table.h' file not found [Mac OS Sierra]

Tags: python, macos, compilation, cmake

I am trying to compile player 3.0.2 and player 3.1.0 but I get the following error on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4 with Intel Core i5.

```
[  0%] Built target playercommon
[  1%] Generating player_interfaces.h
[  1%] Built target player_interfaces
[  2%] Building C object libplayerinterface/CMakeFiles/playerinterface.dir/interface_util.o
/Users/victor/src/player-3.0.2/libplayerinterface/interface_util.c:51:10: fatal error: 
      'interface_table.h' file not found
#include "interface_table.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libplayerinterface/CMakeFiles/playerinterface.dir/interface_util.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libplayerinterface/CMakeFiles/playerinterface.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue.

I create a [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/playerstage/bugs/377/) on the project page, but I have not got a solution

Comment: There is obviously missed dependency between targets: `add_dependencies(playerinterface ${interface_table_h})`. Not sure how Stack Overflow can help you. If the question about fixing the code by yourself, the question lacks that code. If the question about fixing the code by *someone other*, you have already filled the bugreport on the project site.